# Pushout along closed inclusions - compactly generated spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, proof-explanation

This is from Charles Rezk's notes on compactly generated spaces: see [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/cg-spaces-better.pdf) (p.12, proposition 10.6.)

> Let $i\colon A\to X, f\colon A\to B$ be maps of compactly generated spaces and let $Y$ be a pushout of $i$ and $f$ in the category of topological spaces. Assume that $i$ is a closed embedding and $f$ is a quotient map. Then $Y$ is compactly generated.

There is a certain step I don't understand. Let $g\colon X\to Y$ and $g'\colon B\to Y$ be maps which go with the pushout $Y$. Rezk claims that $(g\times g)^{-1}(\Delta_Y) = \Delta_X\cup (i\times i)((f\times f)^{-1}(\Delta_B))$ *because $i$ is injective* but I can't see why $(g\times g)^{-1}(\Delta_Y) \subseteq (i\times i)((f\times f)^{-1}(\Delta_B))$ (here $\Delta$ denoted the diagonal).

I understand that $g$ is also a quotient map because of the pushout properties.

Is there a mistake?

Comment: You should write $g' : B \to Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rezk does not claim there is the inclusion you say.

The pushout is computed as a pushout of sets, so we have a subspace $A$ of $X$ and an equivalence relation on this subspace (given by $f$). Two points of $X$ are glued if and only if they are equal *or* they are in $A$ and equivalent by the relation. The set $(f×f)^{-1}(_B)$ is the set of couples of points of $A$ we want to glue and we take its image by $i×i$ to know the points in $X$ we glue together.